File read/modify/write successful but file unchanged
Never mind.  Please delete this question.  The problem was in how I was calling the file not the file itself.
I'm a using the following code to output the contents of an array of lines to a file.  The code works perfectly locally.  The code appears to be successful when running on the server according to the debug messages.  The problem is the file is unchanged.  Here's the code:
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
$file = 'newurls.txt';

$data = urldecode($_GET['data']);
list($index, $rest) = explode('~', $data, 2);
list($filePath, $date) = explode('|', $rest, 2);
$filePath = urldecode($filePath);
$date = urldecode($date);

$lines = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

$lines[$index] = $filePath . "|" . $date;

if (false === file_put_contents($file, implode("\n", $lines))) {
    http_response_code(500);
    debug_log("Failed to write to the file.");
    exit;
}
echo " Success";
?>

A line of data looks like this:

/words3/scores.txt|10/19/2023 14:14

Here's the bare minimum code without error checking or debugging information.  It works fine locally, on the server it never updates the file. I've checked the working directory as well.
The file is there because I read it just before writing it.  The permissions seem to be fine (644 on the file 755 on the folder).  A test script in the same folder can create and write to a file.  A test script that opens 'urls.txt', appends to it and closes it works fine on the server.  It's just this block of code (or some other problem I'm not imagining) that's failing me.  Oh, I also tried using file_put_contents with the same result. Any clues?

Your title says read/modify/write cycle. Where is the read and modify part of the code?

I suspect it's writing the file in a different folder than you expect. Try using an absolute pathname for $file.

BTW, fopen/fwrite/fclose can be combined into a call to file_put_contents().

You can try to debug output the result of getcwd() to see where the file gets written.

Please provide a [mcve], along with instructions how to run it, so we don't have to guess what's going on. BTW: Where's your fwrite() error checking?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
